# Give linespace in extjs grid content

Tags: extjs

I have a grid containing name and value columns. In value column I want content to have line spaces in between. I'm loading it from the grid store.It seems that "\n" and "\r\n" is not working in extjs.

Plz help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape sequence will not work. Moreover, why exactly do you need extra line space? If you think you need to forcefully add them, one way is to introduce `<br/>` in your content. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zKWAR/).